# Showing the overview of section in beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning

I am making a presentation in beamer, and I want to display overview of the whole document at the beginning and overview of upcoming section. But I have too many sections and subsections, so the default table of contents gets too much crowded. I want to do either of two things:

1) Have the main table of contents that contains only section titles. (I know, I can use `\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\ }`. But it gives unnatural spacing). Also, have an expanded version of table of contents that **expands** only the current section into subsections. Note that I can gray-out the other subsections, but they still take up space, I don't want to do that.

OR

2) Have the main table of content same as above. Also, a slide that contains only the section title expanded into subsections (without mention of other sections).

Also, I want these things to be automated, and I don't want to add a frame manually by myself when I start a new section, because there are so many sections and I may forget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you opt for option 1. (showing only section titles), you could use `hideallsubsections` option which shows only sections. Maybe it will fix your spacing problem (you should have given a MWE to allow testing).

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}
```

This option fits well with a presentation at every new section of its detailed contents. Here is a code for that (to put just after `\begin{document}` which use `hideothersubections`:

```
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}{Outline}
  \small \tableofcontents[currentsection, hideothersubsections]
  \end{frame} 
}
```

If you opt for option 2. (having a big table of contents on several slides), you could decide to put only one section per slide:

```
\tableofcontents[sections={1}]
```

You could also be interested in showing the whole table of contents on two columns. Here is [an example](http://mcclinews.free.fr/latex/introbeamer/elements_diaporama.html):

[image]

```
\begin{frame}{Plan}
  \begin{columns}[t]
  \begin{column}{5cm}
  \tableofcontents[sections={1-4},currentsection, hideothersubsections]
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{5cm}
  \tableofcontents[sections={5-8},currentsection,hideothersubsections]
  \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

And there is the `allowframebreaks` option to display a classic talbe of contents on several slides:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

Comment: This works! I just modified the second code to remove 'currectsection' to display other sections normally, rather than in grey. Just curious -- is there any option to completely hide the other sections rather than in grey?

Comment: Also, the bullets associated with the subsections in 'Outline' (second code) are no longer triangles - they reverted to the default ugly blue circles. Is there way to make them triangles?

Comment: To display only the current section and completely hide the other sections, use `\tableofcontents[currentsection,sectionstyle=show/hide]`. The first argument of `sectionstyle` is applied for the current section (show) and the second (hide) for the other.

Comment: I figured \tableofcontents[sections = \thesection] works too! :-)

Comment: To change bullets associated with the subsections, you could use `\useinnertheme{rectangles}`. It's working for circles also but not for triangles. It depends also of your theme.